# openssl custom attribute during creation

Tags: attributes, openssl, certificate, creation

during the execution of :

```
openssl req -new
```

it asked for some attributes:

```
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:IT
State or Province Name (full name) []:Rome
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:Rome
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:PP
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Information Technology
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:test
Email Address []:test at test dot it

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:claudio
An optional company name []:cc
```

is it possible to add an additional custom attribute during the creation?

Thank you in advance
Claudio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
1) login as root
2) open file openssl.cnf
3) add your custom attribute in "[new oids]" section
4) add description in "req_distinguished_name" section
5) save & close
6) create your new certificate

[ new oids]
 newCustom=1.2.3.4.5.6

[req_distinguished_name] 
 newCustom             = new custom attibute

openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
nter pass phrase for server.key:
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
new custom attribute []: 
..
..
..
```

I hope this could help!

Regards
Claudio

Comment: can you please explain the ``1.2.3.4.5.6`` What does it mean?

Comment: When updating my .cnf there's no prompt for the new attribute

Comment: I do this setting a XYZ=1.2.3.4.5.6 and then when I inspect the cert instead of having a XYZ=My Value it has a 1.2.3.4.5.6=My Value which is not what I need.

Comment: If I want to validate the new custom field, how can I achieve this? I add the self-signed cert. in the store, so it gets validated. But if I want to validate this particular new field, how? I use python: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ssl.html

Comment: 1.2.3.4.5.6 is the id of your newCustom, actually there are default OIDs you can find them at http://www.oid-info.com @Bernhard

Comment: `1.2` is reserved for ISO member bodies, so don't use that prefix.

Comment: Also, this defines a custom RDN, not a custom attribute.